# How to dynamically load a component from state array?

Tags: reactjs

In `useState` I have two values that correspond to two components, how can I map over the state array and load the corresponding component?

Sandboox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-kowalevski-j29w3?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Snare = () => {
  return <div>Snare</div>;
};

const Gong = () => {
  return <div>Gong</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [drums, setDrums] = useState([Snare, Gong]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {drums.map((drum, index) => (
        <drum /> // <== How to dynamically load the Snare and Gong components??
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Capitalize the `drum`, so React knows its a component.

Comment: yes that did it, thank you